# Spin off a command line process from an ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, security, windows-server-2003, file-permissions, 7zip

I have a web page hosted on the server and a zip file on the server's file system. The page is spinning off the 7zip process with some arguments (location of the zip file and destination folder for unzipping) but it seems to raise permission issues, of course. For each file in the archive I get "Can not open file [filename]". I tried windows authentication and running the process with a username and password but nothing worked properly. What would be the best way for unzipping the file on the server from security point of view? Ideally, I would also like to have this event driven so the file is unzipped as soon as it arrives on the server (this is when I request the page). Other solutions are welcome but simplicity/lightweight solution is preferred.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of an open or closed source zip library

e.g.:
http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ or
http://www.sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/